# Why is performance different when using AddDbContext vs AddSqlite in EF core 6?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am working on .NET 6 Web API project and trying to setup connection to Sqlite database using EF 6.
As a reference I used this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/build-web-api-minimal-database/5-exercise-use-sqlite-database

In **Program.cs**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
builder.Services.AddSqlite<AppDb>(connectionString);
```

It worked but every query took 30 seconds to execute (+-100ms), including trivial ones like selecting one row in a table that has only one row.

After that I switched to this:

In **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDb>();
```

In **AppDb.cs**

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlite(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));
}
```

This implementation has superior performance, everything get executed in under 1 second.
I am wondering why is that? One thing I noticed is that in the first case I get .db-journal Sqlite files and in the second case there are .db-wal files.

Comment: Probably asking the obvious but I assume in both cases the connection string is equal?

Comment: @GertArnold yes, everything is exactly the same except the things I written above. Connection string is "Data Source=Data.db"

Comment: Could you put together a minimal repro demonstrating the difference and [submit a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose) so we can investigate?